Floor function in Q# thinks everything is an Int
I am currently doing the Azure quantum katas learning module, and I have reached a problem where I have to use Floor to normalize an angle so that it is always between -π and π. So I have written the following code in Q#
namespace Kata {
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Math;

    function ComplexPolarMult(x : ComplexPolar, y : ComplexPolar) : ComplexPolar {
        let (r1, theta1) = (x.Magnitude, x.Argument);
        let (r2, theta2) = (y.Magnitude, y.Argument);
        let r3 = r1 * r2;
        mutable theta3 = theta1 + theta2;

        set theta3 = theta3 - 2.0 * PI() * Floor((theta3 + PI()) / (2.0 * PI()));

        return ComplexPolar(r3, theta3);
    }
}

But I always get type error: expected Double, found Int. I mean always: I get the same error with Floor(PI()) and Floor(2.7) and Floor((Double)2.7) I have first ran into this issue with the online IDE but it also happens in the IDE on my own machine. Thanks in advance.
